# powershell modify '.\' and invoke .ps1

Tags: powershell, path, environment-variables

I'm trying to invoke a powershell script that in turn runs various .SQL files.
It looks something like this:

Script1 (Invoke_createdb.ps1):

```
$scriptPath = "C:\scriptpath"
$dbUser = "dbuser1"
$dbPassword = "dbpassword1"
$dbInstance = "dbserver1"
$dbName = "Database1"
& $scriptPath\createdb.ps1 -dbInstance $dbInstance -dbUser $dbUser -dbPassword $dbPassword -dbName $dbName
```

Script2 (createdb.ps1):

```
param
(
$dbInstance = $(Read-Host "database server"),
$dbaUser = $(Read-Host "dba user"),
$dbaPassword = $(Read-Host "password of dba user"),
$dbName = $(Read-Host "Database Name")
)

Invoke-Expression "sqlcmd.exe -S $dbInstance -U $dbaUser -P $dbaPassword -i .\create.sql"
Invoke-Expression "sqlcmd.exe -S $dbInstance -d $dbName -U $dbaUser -P $dbaPassword -i .\MSSQLScripts\Create\TABLES.SQL"

$storedProcedures = Get-ChildItem .\MSSQLScripts\Shared\*.sql
foreach ($storedProcedure in $storedProcedures)
{  
Invoke-Expression "sqlcmd.exe -S $dbInstance -d $dbName -U $dbaUser -P $dbaPassword -i $storedProcedure"
}
```

This seems simple in principle, and works if the second script is run on its own.
The issue I have appears when the 2nd script is invoked by the 1st, as the '.\' is no longer relative and breaks. It becomes unable to find anything using `.\`.

It is not possible to modify 'Script2' as it is required to run relative to itself in other scenarios and is updated periodically with additional procedures, but I need to invoke it within the first script.

I have tried modifying the `$env:PATH` and `$env:ROOT` variables but I have had no success.

Does anyone know of a clean way that I can (1) invoke the second script and at the same time (2) set the relative path so that it runs successfully when invoked?

Thanks for any assistance.

**Edit: I have temporarily tested with success by modifying each mention of `.\` in the 2nd script to a definite UNC path, but as noted, the script will not run when run in other environments.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you change current directory prior to call the script.

```
...
Push-Location $scriptPath
$scriptPath\createdb.ps1 -dbInstance $dbInstance -dbUser $dbUser -dbPassword $dbPassword -dbName $dbName
Pop-Location
```